# Python Parse specific attributes from dynamic XML Array and combine data

Tags: python, arrays, xml

I have an XML data that I get from a URL that I need to parse specific elements/attributes and assign them to variables so I can write them to XLSX later on. I'm getting stuck on trying to combine the variables into a nice List so they're in order. The SkillNameUriPair/competencelevel are dynamic in that some resources have it but some don't and some can have multiples. How do I combine what I get there with the userID, firstName, etc?

I'm going on about 3 weeks here programming with Python with no prior experience programming except googling a lot. Any advise would be greatly appreciated! Hope it's something I'm overlooking.

Sample XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <self>https://abc.local/adminapi/resource/jon</self>
        <userID>jon</userID>
        <firstName>Jon</firstName>
        <lastName>Smith</lastName>
        <extension>1498</extension>
         <skillMap>
            <skillCompetency>
                <competencelevel>5</competencelevel>
                <skillNameUriPair name="Test">
                    <refURL>https://abc.local/adminapi/skill/3</refURL>
                </skillNameUriPair>
            </skillCompetency>
           <skillCompetency>
                <competencelevel>5</competencelevel>
                <skillNameUriPair name="CallCenter">
                    <refURL>https://abc.local/adminapi/skill/2</refURL>
                </skillNameUriPair>
            </skillCompetency>
        </skillMap>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <self>https://abc.local/adminapi/resource/MMath</self>
        <userID>mikem</userID>
        <firstName>Mike</firstName>
        <lastName>Math</lastName>
        <extension>1303</extension>
        <skillMap/>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Desired result:

> [(userID, firstName, lastName, extension, ](skillNameUriPair, competencelevel), (skillNameUriPair, competencelevel),(skillNameUriPair, competencelevel),(skillNameUriPair, competencelevel)]]
>
> [('jon', 'Jon', 'Smith', '1498', None,)('mmath', 'Mike', 'Math',
>   '1303', [('5', 'Test'), ('5', 'CallCenter')]]

Current Code Snippet:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(response.content))
    resource = tree.findall('./resource')
    for child in resource:
        userID = child.find('userID').text
        firstName = child.find('firstName').text
        lastName = child.find('lastName').text
        extension = child.find('extension').text
        skillMap = child.find('skillMap')
        for child_b in skillMap:
            child_c = child_b.findall('competencelevel')
            child_d = child_b.findall('skillNameUriPair')
            for clevel in child_c:
                competencelevel = clevel.text
            for skills in child_d:
                skillNameUriPair = skills.get('name')
            values = competencelevel, skillNameUriPair
            skill.append(values)
        value = userID, firstName, lastName, extension, skill
        list.append(value)
    print(list)
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance...

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: When I run the script, the skillNameUriPair and competence level end up being populated to each user even the ones that shouldn't have any. Here's what it ends up showing:

Comment: [('mikem', 'Mike', 'Math', '1303', [('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'OutboundSales'), ('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'OnLineBanking'), ('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'OnLineBanking'), ('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'Collections_Agent5'), ('5', 'OutboundSales'), ('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'Collections_Agent5'), ('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'OutboundSales'), ('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'OutboundSales'), ('5', 'OutboundSales'), ('5', 'CallCenter'), ('5', 'Collections_Agent5'), ('5', 'Collections_Agent5'), ('5', 'CallCenter'),,...

Comment: So it almost seems like the "for child_b in skillMap:" step isn't only checking for 1 user but all users and returning everything instead.